# How to search multiple text nodes for a String

Tags: javascript, jquery, search

I currently have a script that searches a page for a word that a user types and highlights the word if it is found.

This fails, however, when the user puts a space in the string they are searching for, since I'm using jQuery to split the document text into Nodes, and checking if each one contains the current search phrase.

What I would like to be able to do is to expand this to search for a user-defined string, instead of failing after the first space. I'm not sure how to do this at all, though, so I was hoping someone could help me out here.

Here's what I'm currently working with, to find the nodes:

```
keyup(function({

    $(instance.textWrapper).html(instance.getOriginalText());               

    if (this.value.length >= instance.startSearchingLength) {

        var regx = new RegExp("(" + escape(this.value) + ")", 'gi');

        $(instance.textWrapper).each(function() {
            var textNodes = $(this).find('*').contents().filter(function(){
                return this.nodeType === 3
        });

        textNodes.each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            var content = $this.text();
            content = content.replace(regx, 
                                      '<span class="'
                                      + instance.highlightCssClass +
                                      '">$1</span>');
            $this.replaceWith(content);     
        });
    });
}
```

`startSearchingLength` is defined earlier as the length the search must be to be searched.
`highlightCssClass` is just what to the CSS class to wrap the string in once it is found.

Example of failure:

Searching for `foo bar` will highlight each instance of `foo` on the page, but as soon as the space is encountered, those highlights go away and the full string cannot be found.

So, the code currently searches each individual `Text Node` for the search query, but I'm hoping to make the script find any string in all of the text of the file. I have no idea how to do this, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: And what about `regx`? Don't forget a concrete example when it fails while you are at it

Comment: Hang on, I'll edit this real quick, sorry about that

Comment: I remember recently sharing [this](http://codemirror.net/) link for a related post. It _might_ help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple. You are using the wrong escaping. Drop that `escape`.

```
this.value.replace(/([[\\^$.|?*+()])/g, "\\$1")
```

What you have to escape are the regular expression's reserved characters.

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking it was a completely separate issue, so you saved me a lot of time.